# How to copy specific columns from a single row from one google spreadsheet to another google spreadsheet using google apps script with an event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to move(copy) certain columns from one specific row in a specific sheet in a spreadsheet into another spreadsheet when selecting a value from a drop down list from a specific cell in that same row. But I want it to the copied cells to go in a specific place in the new spreadsheet sheet (not simply on as the first or last row).

Let's say I have Cols A B C with the data I want to transfer. But I only want to transfer the data on row 5 for example. And Col J has a data validation on every row with a drop down that says "move data", so when I select that option, only that specific range (Cols ABC on row 5) would be copied into the new spreadsheet - let's say I want it to go into row 15, col E F G.

I appreciate in advance for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Let's say I have Cols A B C with the data I want to transfer. But I only want to transfer the data on row 5 for example. And Col J has a data validation on every row with a drop down that says "move data", so when I select that option, only that specific range (Cols ABC on row 5) would be copied into the new spreadsheet - let's say I want it to go into row 15, col E F G.`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? And, can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();;
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value= 'movedata') {
    const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
    const dsh = dss.getSheetByName('destination sheet name');
    const drg = dsh.getRange(15, 5, 1, 3).setValues(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 3).getValues());
  }
}
```

I think you may need an installable trigger but you can try a simple trigger first. I could be wrong. I haven't test it so don't assume everything is correct.  You will need to put the correct sheet names in.